# How to convert my web site from cakephp 1.3 to cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to convert my current web site which was developed in cakephp 1.3 .
Now i want to convert my whole website into cakephp 2.0 .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for 1.3 to 2.0 migration guides such as this one https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/master/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.rst

Comment: also note the improvements coming up for the upgrade shell: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2117-improvements-for-20-upgrade-shell